# Show that $(x + 1)^{(2n + 1)} + x^{(n + 2)}$ can be divided by $x^2 + x + 1$ without remainder

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

I am in my pre-academic year. We recently studied the Remainder sentence (at least that's what I think it translates) which states that any polynomial can be written as $P = Q\cdot L + R$

I am unable to solve the following:

> Show that $(x + 1)^{(2n + 1)} + x^{(n + 2)}$ can be divided by $x^2 + x + 1$ without remainder.

Comment: Its remainder *theorem* rather than *sentence*.

Comment: Note that it is important that the degree of $R$ is less than the degree of the divisor, so the remainder you will expect here has degree at most $1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $n=0$, then it is trivial.

For $n>0$, we have $$(x+1)^{2n+1}+x^{n+2}\\=(x^2+2x+1)(x+1)^{2n-1}+x^{n+2}\\=(x^2+x+1)(x+1)^{2n-1}+x(x+1)^{2n-1}+x^{n+2}\\=(x^2+x+1)(x+1)^{2n-1}+x((x+1)^{2n-1}+x^{n+1})$$. 
By using induction, suppose $(x+1)^{2n-1}+x^{n+1}$ can be divided by $x^2+x+1$, then, $(x+1)^{2n+1}+x^{n+2}$ also can be divided by  $x^2+x+1$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4373436/589

Answer (score 10):

Suppose $a$ is a root of $x^2+x+1=0$, then we have both $$a+1=-a^2$$ and $$a^3=1$$

Let $f(x)=(x+1)^{2n+1}+x^{n+2}$ then $$f(a)=(-a^2)^{2n+1}+a^{n+2}=-a^{4n+2}+a^{n+2}=-a^{n+2}+a^{n+2}=0$$

Since the two distinct roots of the quadratic are also roots of $f(x)$ we can use the remainder theorem to conclude that the remainder is zero.

Comment: Wow this was a really neat approach. I considered showing roots of the one are roots of the other but the way I was thinking was going to be time consuming. +1

Comment: @MathsSurvivor multiply by $a$ to get $a^2+a=-a^3$ and then also $a^2+a=-1$. If you multiply $x^2+x+1$  by $x-1$ you get $x^3-1$, which is why this works as it does. You are working with cube roots of $1$. If you work this out in arithmetic and algebra (do the calculations, become familiar with them so they are obvious, assume the roots exist and explore her properties) you will be well ahead when it comes to more advanced work, because you will have an example of how he links work.

Comment: @MarkBennet Yeah I get it now , thank you very much , one more question isn't $\text{a}$ supposed to be the only root of $x^2+x+1$ that is also root of f(x) , so why then did you write at the end "Since the TWO distinct roots of the quadratic are also roots of f(x)"?

Comment: @MathsSurvivor Most quadratics have two roots - see the quadratic formula. They have one root (a double root) iff the discriminant is zero. The remainder here will be of the form $r(x)=px+q$. If the roots are $a$ and $b$ we find that $r(a)=r(b)=0$ from which we conclude $p=q=0$ (a straight line through two distinct points on the axis is  the axis - so here it is important that the two roots are distinct).

Comment: @MarkBennet Okay I understand it now, thank you very much  :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try to check if complex roots of $x^2+x+1$ are also roots for $(x+1)^{2n+1}+x^{n+2}$.

Also there is another way to prove it. Let see that $((x+1)^2-x)\cdot (x+1)^{2n-1}$ also divided by $x^2+x+1$. So we just need to prove that $x\cdot (x+1)^{2n-1}+x^{n+2}$ is divided by $x^2+x+1$. In this way we can come to prove that $(x^k\cdot (x+1)^{2n+1-2\cdot k}+x^{n+2}), \dots ,$ $(x^n(x+1)+x^{n+2})$ are all divided by $x^2+x+1$. But it's true, because $x^n(x+1)+x^{n+2} = x^n(x^2+x+1) $

Comment: This is really neat, although complex roots are an excellent way, Id rather stay away from it at this point. Can you please clarify the first steps of the second solution?

Comment: Sorry, I understood now.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x+1)^{2n+1}+x^{n+2}=(x+1)\{(x+1)^2\}^n+x^{n+2}=(x+1)(x^2+2x+1)^n+x^{n+2}$$

Now as $x^2+2x+1\equiv x\pmod{x^2+x+1}$

$$(x+1)(x^2+2x+1)^n+x^{n+2}\equiv (x+1)(x)^n+x^{n+2}\pmod{x^2+x+1}$$

$$\equiv x^n(x+1+x^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

I am going to prove it by modulo. In modulo $$
x^{2}+x+1 \equiv 0\left(\bmod x^{2}+x+1\right) \Rightarrow x+1\equiv -x^2\textrm{ and } x^3 \equiv 1 \left(\bmod x^{2}+x+1\right).
$$
In modulo $x^{2}+x+1$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
(x+1)^{2 n+1}+x^{n+2} \equiv &\left(-x^{2}\right)^{2 n+1}+x^{n+2} \\
\equiv &-x^{4 n+2}+x^{n+2} \\
\equiv & x^{n+2}\left(1-x^{3 n}\right) \\
\equiv & x^{n+2}\left(1-1\right) \\
\equiv & 0
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore it has no remainder when divided by $x^{2}+x+1$.