# Proving divisibility by induction

Tags: polynomials, induction, divisibility, binomial-theorem

The problem consists of demonstrating through induction that $\forall a \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n\geq 0$ (where $n$ is an integer)
$$(a^2+a+1)\mid(a^{n+2} +(a+1)^{2n+1})$$
That is, $a^2+a+1$ divides $a^{n+2}+(a+1)^{2n+1}$.

My work so far:

Considering the base cases, $n=0$ is trivial.

For $n=1$, since $a^2+a+1$ must divide $a^3+(a+1)^{3}$, there must exist $b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$b(a^2+a+1) = 2a^3+3a^2+3a+1$$
which turns out to be
$$b = 2a+1$$
that is
$$(2a+1)(a^2+a+1)=2a^3+3a^2+3a+1$$

For $n=2$
$$b(a^2+a+1) = a^4+(a+1)^5$$
$$(a^3+c_1a^2+c_2a+1)(a^2+a+1) = a^5 +6a^4+10a^3+10a^2+5a+1$$
which turns out to be
$$b=a^3+5a^2+4a+1$$
that is
$$(a^3+5a^2+4a+1)(a^2+a+1)=a^5+6a^4+10a^3+10a^2+5a+1$$
It is clear that this becomes a problem of factoring polynomials generated by $a^{n+2}+(a+1)^{2n+1}$ such that it always has a factor of $a^2+a+1$.

Now, assuming that this is true for $n=k$, that is
$$b(a^2+a+1)=a^{k+2}+(a+1)^{2k+1}$$
$$\left(\sum_{p=0}^{2k-1}{c'}_pa^{2k-1-p}\right)(a^2+a+1)=a^{k+2}+(a+1)^{2k+1}$$
where $\sum_{p=0}^{2k-1}{c'}_pa^{2k-1-p}$ is a polynomial of degree 2 less than $(a+1)^{2k+1}$ and ${c'}_p$ are arbitrary (for now) coefficients of the factorization process.

Then, for $n=k+1$
$$\left(\sum_{p=0}^{2k+1}c_pa^{2k+1-p}\right)(a^2+a+1)=a^{k+3}+(a+1)^{2k+3}$$
idealy I would be able to extract a factor of $a^2+a+1$ from the LHS and relate the two polynomials, but I haven't been able to, also I can't see a way to use the assumption of $n=k$ being true to help prove the case for $n=k+1$ since the coefficients ${c'}_p$ and $c_p$ need not be the same. Working on the LHS
$$a^2a^{k+1}+\sum_{p=0}^{2k+3}\binom{2k+3}{p}a^{2k+3-p}$$
$$=a^2a^{k+1} + a^2\sum_{p=0}^{2k+1}\binom{2k+3}{p}a^{2k+1-p} + \sum_{p=2k+2}^{2k+3}\binom{2k+3}{p}a^{2k+3-p}$$
adding and subtracting $a^2\sum_{p=0}^{k}a^{2k+1-p}$ and $a^2\sum_{p=k+2}^{2k+1}a^{2k+1-p}$
$$a^2\sum_{p=0}^{2k+1}a^{2k+1-p} - a^2\sum_{p=0}^{2k-1}\left(a^{2k+1-p}+a^{2k-1-p} \right) + a^2\sum_{p=0}^{2k+1}\binom{2k+3}{p}a^{2k+1-p} + \sum_{p=2k+2}^{2k+3}\binom{2k+3}{p}a^{2k+3-p}$$
extracting a factor of $a^2+a+1$ from $\sum_{p=0}^{2k+1}\binom{2k+3}{p}a^{2k+1-p}$ and changing the index of $\sum_{p=2k+2}^{2k+3}\binom{2k+3}{p}a^{2k+3-p}$ by a factor of 2
$$a^2\sum_{p=0}^{2k+1}a^{2k+1-p}-a^2\sum_{p=0}^{2k-1}\left(a^{2k+1-p}+a^{2k-1-p}\right) + \sum_{p=0}^{2k+1}\binom{2k+3}{p}a^{2k+1-p}(a^2+a+1) - \sum_{p=0}^{2k+1}\binom{2k+3}{p}a^{2k+1-p}(a+1)+ \sum_{p=2k}^{2k+1}\binom{2k+1}{p}a^{2k+1-p}$$
however I don't know how to continue from here since this is becoming a mess and I haven't been able to extract a factor of $a^2+a+1$ from all terms. The only thing I tried to accomplish is to have all terms with summation run from $0$ to $2k+1$, but seems to have failed.

Can somebody help me with the following steps of this proof?

Comment: FYI, rather than using `|` to get something like $a|b$, it's better to use `\mid` to get something like $a \mid b$ (i.e., it gives better horizontal spacing). Also, for not divides, note using `\not|` gives $a\not|b$ while using `\not\mid` or `\nmid` gives $a \nmid b$ instead.

Comment: Let $u:=a^2,\,v:=a+1$. Since $\color{red}{u+v|u^{2n+1}+v^{2n+1}}$, it suffices to prove $a^2+a+1|a^{n+2}(a^{3n}-1)$, which follows from $\color{blue}{a^3-1|a^{3n}-1}$. Technically, both coloured facts require a proof by induction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $(x + 1)^{(2n + 1)} + x^{(n + 2)}$ can be divided by $x^2 + x + 1$ without remainder](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757702/show-that-x-12n-1-xn-2-can-be-divided-by-x2-x-1-wit). This is actually somewhat more general as $x$ is not limited to being an integer, with this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/757709/602049) there showing one way to prove it using induction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different take based on linear recurrences.

Let $x_n = a^{n+2} +(a+1)^{2n+1} = a^2 a^n + (a+1)((a+1)^2)^n = a^2 A^n + (a+1)B^n$, with $A=a$ and $B=(a+1)^2$. Then, $x_{n+2}=(A+B)x_{n+1}-ABx_n$. The claim follows at once by induction if it holds for $x_0$ and $x_1$, which is simple to check.